# Передача базы в Android приложение

Tags: android, api

Доброго времени суток!
   Как начинающего, заинтересовал вопрос: как наиболее эффективно передать базу с удаленного сервера в андроид-приложение.
   Напрашивается такой способ. Создать базу в андроиде.  Через API закачать данные. Далее - через ContentValues записать в базу закаченное.
   Мне кажется, не совсем экономный способ. Наверное, проще было бы качнуть базу с сервера в приложение. Только пока не понимаю, как это сделать. Использовать механизм, наподобие копирования базы из файла? Только входящий поток будет не из assets, а из API. Или другой способ? 
   Где можно почитать про это?

Comment: Данные одни для всех? Обьем данных?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется самый адекватный способ без всяких костылей следующий:

1.Вы отправляете запрос на сервер

2.Сервер отдает данные

3.Вы эти данные сохраняете в базу данных у себя на телефоне

4.Раз в определенное проверять на актуальность данных.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, а какие методы при этом используются?

Comment: Можно использовать TinyDB, как для ArrayList с кастомным классом, так и со String. Вы же планируете в массив получить данные с БД?

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев что ты имеешь ввиду?) Про какие методы тебе рассказать?

Comment: методы Java/Android в таком случае.)) Я, к примеру, думал, что здесь задействованы методы ContentProvider.

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев вопрос еще актуальный?

Comment: Уже не актуальный